# How to get the cumulative sum by group in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a dataframe such that:

```
df<-data.frame(id=1:8,group=c(1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0),rep=c(rep("d1",4),rep("d2",4)),value=rbinom(8,1,0.6))
df
  id group rep value
1  1     1  d1     0
2  2     0  d1     0
3  3     0  d1     0
4  4     1  d1     1
5  5     1  d2     1
6  6     0  d2     0
7  7     1  d2     1
8  8     0  d2     1
```

What's the best way to get the cumulative sum by `group` and `rep` such that:

```
cumsum
group d1  d1+d2  d1+d2+d3
0     0     1      ...
1     1     3      ...
```

Comment: `cumsum` is a function. Type `?cumsum`. There is also a `by` function, which has documentation linking to similar functions (type `?by` and look under "See also")... so, `by(df$value,df$group,cumsum)` is one way

Comment: May you give an answer using the demo? +1

Comment: To get it all in a data frame: `do.call(rbind, by(df$value,df$group,cumsum))`

Comment: Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : could not find function "FUN"

Comment: The questions are even not similar if you look closely.

Comment: Oh weird -- my comment disappeared. Anyway, I was saying that @josilber meant `do.call(cbind,...` which will not give an error. Ah, I see that your question is quite unique. I went off the title instead of your desired output initially.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
library(data.table)

# convert to data.table in place
setDT(df)

# dcast and do individual sums
dt.cast = dcast.data.table(df, group ~ rep, value.var = 'value',
                           fun.aggregate = sum)
dt.cast
#   group d1 d2
#1:     0  0  1
#2:     1  1  2

# cumsum
dt.cast[, as.list(cumsum(unlist(.SD))), by = group]
#   group d1 d2
#1:     0  0  1
#2:     1  1  3
```

Answer (score 17):

I'd recommend working with the
[tidy](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html) form of the data.
Here's an approach with dplyr, but it would be trivial to translate to
data.table or base R.

First I'll create the dataset, setting the random seed to make the
example reproducible:

```
set.seed(1014)
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:8,
  group = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0),
  rep = c(rep("d1", 4), rep("d2", 4)),
  value = rbinom(8, 1, 0.6)
)
df

%>   id group rep value
%> 1  1     1  d1     1
%> 2  2     0  d1     0
%> 3  3     0  d1     0
%> 4  4     1  d1     1
%> 5  5     1  d2     1
%> 6  6     0  d2     1
%> 7  7     1  d2     1
%> 8  8     0  d2     1
```

Next, using dplyr, I'll first collapse to individual rows by group, and
then compute the cumulative sum:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% 
  group_by(group, rep) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>%
  mutate(csum = cumsum(value))
df

%> Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
%> Groups: group
%> 
%>   group rep value csum
%> 1     0  d1     0    0
%> 2     0  d2     2    2
%> 3     1  d1     2    2
%> 4     1  d2     2    4
```

For most cases, you're best of leaving the data in this form (it will be
easier to work for), but you can reshape if you need to:

```
library(reshape2)

dcast(df, group ~ rep, value.var = "csum")

%>   group d1 d2
%> 1     0  0  2
%> 2     1  2  4
```