# Cumulative total by group

Tags: r, data.table

For the following dataset:

```
d = data.frame(date = as.Date(as.Date('2015-01-01'):as.Date('2015-04-10'), origin = "1970-01-01"),
               group = rep(c('A','B','C','D'), 25), value = sample(1:100))
head(d)
         date group value
1: 2015-01-01     A     4
2: 2015-01-02     B    32
3: 2015-01-03     C    46
4: 2015-01-04     D    40
5: 2015-01-05     A    93
6: 2015-01-06     B    10
```

.. can anyone advise a more elegant way to calculate a cumulative total of values by group than this [data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23020101/1156245)) method?

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)
d.cast = dcast.data.table(d, group ~ date, value.var = 'value', fun.aggregate = sum)
c.sum = d.cast[, as.list(cumsum(unlist(.SD))), by = group]
```

.. which is pretty clunky and yields a flat matrix that needs `dplyr::gather` or `reshape2::melt` to reformat.

Surely R can do better than this??

Comment: I'm confused. What you describe in words is `setDT(d)[,cumsum(value),by=group]`

Comment: You should really use `set.seed()` to make the example [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and you should also include the desired output for your sample input.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you just want cumulative sums per group, then you can do

```
transform(d, new=ave(value,group,FUN=cumsum))
```

with base R.

Comment: Tick for a hole in one, and preserving original data order :)

Answer (score 8):

This should work

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  mutate(Total = cumsum(value))
```

Comment: This is probably the direction of best practice though

Comment: Fortran is better. Binary is best.

Answer (score 4):

As this question was tagged with `data.table`, you are probably looking for (a modification of @Franks comment).

```
setDT(d)[order(date), new := cumsum(value), by = group]
```

This will simultaneously rearrange the data by `date` (not sure if needed, if not, you can get rid of `order(date)`) and update your data set *in place* utilizing the `:=` operator

Comment: @akrun I'm not as popular as Flick probably ;)

Comment: Actually I didn't add that tag I think @Frank did.  Spologies I should've rolled back sooner

Comment: I don't think you need `order(date)` (as you mention).

Comment: didn't know you can use `order` as an `i` argument. +1!

Answer (score 0):

Is this it?

```
sp <- split(d, d$group)
res <- lapply(seq_along(sp), function(i) cumsum(sp[[i]]$value))
res <- lapply(seq_along(res), function(i){
        sp[[i]]$c.sum <- res[[i]]
        sp[[i]]
    }) 
res <- do.call(rbind, res)
res
```